# Access Specific Header from JQuery Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm performing a POST Method using JQuery

```
var params = JSON.stringify({ UserName: usr, Password: pwd });
        var temp = $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'some-url',
            data: params,
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                var ResponseCode = data.responseJSON.ResponseCode;
                var ResponseMessage = data.responseJSON.ResponseMessage;
                var TokenKey = data.responseJSON.TokenKey;
                var UserName = data.responseJSON.UserName;
                var type = data.responseJSON.Type;

                if (ResponseCode == 100 && type == 1) {
                    window.open("page2.html", "_self");

                }
                else if (ResponseCode == 100 && type == 0) {
                    window.open("page1.html", "_self");
                }
                else if (ResponseCode != 100) {
                    alert(temp.getAllResponseHeaders);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error")
            }
        });
```

now i can successfully find all the required data in the response body but there is some a specific header which i wish to put into a variable

i tried implementing the following lines withing the COMPLETE sector

```
var h = request.getHeader("Authorization-Token");

var h = request.getAllHeaders("Authorization-Token");
```

yet i'm always getting null or undefined Any help or suggestion is Much appreciated

Comment: You had not pass `header` in `ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

On your server, you will need to add this header to the response:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization-Token
```

Comment: i added it but yet same results is there is any special method to get access to headers???